# how new traverse api works

Tags: neo4j, graph-traversal

nowadaya i m learning new traverse api of neo4j and i followed the link below

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html

so now i know how to use uniqueness,evaluater etc.
that is i know how to change beahviours of the api.

but the thing i want to know is that how exactly it traverse.

for example im trying to find neighbours of a node.

does neo4j use index to find this?
does neo4j keep a hash to find neighbours?

more specifically, when i write the following code for example.

```
TraversalDescription desc = database.traversalDescription().breadthFirst().evaluator( Evaluators.toDepth( 3) );

node =database.getNodeById(4601410);

Traverser traverser = desc.traverse(node);
```

in my description i used breadthFirst. So it means that when i give node to traverse, the code should find the first neighbours. So how the api finds the first neighbours is the thing i want to know. Is there a pointer to neighbours in node? So when i say traverse until to depth 3 it finds the first neighbours and then take the neighbours as node in a recursive function and so on? So if we say to depth 10 then it can be slow?

so what i want exactly is how i can change the natural behaviour of the api to traverse?

Comment: Please be more specific - how do you want to change the behavior?  What kind of traversal do you want to do?   There are built-in ones (depth-first, breadth-first, etc) - and you can customize and do just about whatever you want, but "how to change the natural behavior" depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits i want to know how the api traverse to find another nodes? How it reaches a node from the given node? Please see my edit

Comment: Neo4j is open source, you can look at the implementation yourself at github, for example https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/28484b2ca5a6cff28ff4003dfab6c8e2e39c4594/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/traversal/BidirectionalTraversalDescriptionImpl.java , or on your own computer in the editor/IDE that you are using.

Comment: @jjaderberg of course i can look at. But if you check you can easily see it is really complicated and i m looking something (explanation,way, etc.) to understand it quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified, Neo4j stores records representing nodes and relationships a.s.o. in its store. Every node is represented by a node record on disk, that record contains a pointer (direct offset into relationship store) for the first relationship (neighbour if you will). Relationship records link to each other, so getting all neighbours for a node will read the node record, its relationship pointer to that relationship record and continue following those forward pointers until the end of that chain. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

TraversalDescription features a concept of [PathExpander](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PathExpander.html) - that is the component deciding which relationships will be used for the next step. Use [TraversalDescription.expand()](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/TraversalDescription.html#expand(org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpander)) for this.

You can either use your own implementation for PathExpander or use one of the predefined methods in [PathExpanders](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PathExpanders.html).

If you just want your traversal follow specific relationship types you can use [TraversalDescription.relationships()](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/TraversalDescription.html) to specify those.